# Сделать кроссдоменный запрос к стороннему серверу

Tags: jquery, xmlhttprequest

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как сделать кроссдоменный запрос к стороннему серверу на jQuery ???
Тестировал на своем хостинге, и если делаю запрос с локального сервера на свой хостинг то ответ я получу только в том случае если на хостинге в файле .htaccess явно прописано

`Header add Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"`,

может я чего не так понимаю, но хотелось бы узнать как сделать запрос не прописывая такой строчки в .htaccess, и возможно ли это ?

Comment: > может я чего не так понимаю, но хотелось бы узнать как сделать запрос не прописывая такой строчки в .htaccess, и возможно ли это ?

Немного перефразирую: без желания владельца сервера - нет.

Comment: То есть выходит пока владелец сервера не пропишет такую строку, то ни как ? Но ведь если пройти по данному адресу в браузере то данные в формате json я увижу, может можно их как то тогда взять ?

Comment: Сделайте запрос к своему серверу, а со своего сервера уже - на нужный вам.

Comment: Легинький гуглинг с утра находит [все](http://habrahabr.ru/post/120336/).

Comment: Хрень какая то, на хабре разжевали все это с каким то сторонним плагином, а саму суть так и не рассказали, может кто может объяснить как это реализовать на JS, не обязательно кроссбраузерно, главное что бы можно было вывести эти данные на страницу 

http://mycitycard.nichost.ru/api/news?id=23

Comment: @kostya без своего прокси нельзя, сделано это для того, чтобы скрипт злоумышленника не мог получить ваши приватные данные на удаленном сервере. (с прокси авторизация удаленного сервера не пройдет - куки сессии и тд)

Comment: @eicto, еще как вариант можно использовать прослойку flash или java, если вдруг есть требование не перезагружать страницу для данных.

Comment: @kostya, кроме CORS есть еще, как минимум, JSONP, но смысл в том, что для получения данных с сервера владельцу сервера тем или иным способом надо разрешить получать эти данные.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Можно:

Есть небольшой трюк с PHP. И этот трюк будет работать не только с Google, но и с любыми сайтами, к которым у вас нет доступа и вы не можете добавить Access-Control-Allow-Origin *

Нам нужно создать PHP-файл (например. getContentFromUrl.php) на нашем сервере и сделать обращение к нему.

**PHP**

```
<?php

$ext_url = $_POST['ext_url'];

echo file_get_contents($ext_url);

?>
```

**JS**

```
$.ajax({
    method: 'POST',
    url: 'getContentFromUrl.php', // link to your PHP file
    data: {
        // url куда наш сервер будет отправлять запрос, который мы не можем сделать через AJAX
        'ext_url': 'https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6114436/access-control-allow-origin-error-sending-a-jquery-post-to-google-apis'
    },
    success: function(data) {
        // теперь мы можем взять любые данные из внешнего url, потому что у нас есть вся страница
        var $h1 = $(data).find('h1').html();

        $('h1').text($h1);
    },
    error:function() {
        console.log('Error');
    }
});
```

**Как это работает:**

1. Ваш браузер с помощью JS отправит запрос на ваш сервер
2. Ваш сервер отправит запрос на любой другой сервер и получит ответ
3. Ваш сервер отправит этот ответ в ваш JS файл

И мы можем добавить event типа onClick на кнопку. Надеюсь, это поможет!

Comment: Здравствуйте! По-моему отличный пример обходного решения, данный к месту и хорошо продемонстрированный. Мне кажется, можно вполне ссылаться на этот вопрос в похожих ситуациях, а также использовать в качестве эталонной "закрывашки" как дубликат. Я правда рекомендую не переусредствовать: не всегда стоит давать полные дубли ответов, иногда уместнее предложить закрыть дубликатом или просто упомянуть в комментариях ссылку на этот вопрос как вариант решения. Скажите, вы в курсе про механизм дубликатов на stackoverflow?

Comment: @AK - я сам долго искал ответ на этот вопрос. И не на русском, ни на английском stackoverflow его не нашёл. Возможно, вы правы, что лучше давать ссылку на правильный, чем дублировать его полностью. Однако ещё важнее, что по разным запросам можно получить решения, путь даже продублированное, верно?

Comment: Вот в дублировании собственно и есть признак некоторой навязчивости. Вполне достаточно в комментариях давать ссылку на этот вопрос, а не копировать ответ один-в-один.

Comment: Ваш php-скрипт выглядит как отличный бэкдор и DoS-усилитель. Надо хотя бы список доменов ограничить...

Comment: Да, вы правы. В плане безопастности - не самое лучшее решение. Им можно воспользоваться, после чего скрипт с сервера удалить и оставить себе на будущие задачи. Например, очень удобно копировать нужный контент со сторонних ресурсов с помощью этой связки. После чего, конечно, можно удалить скрипт с сервера.

Answer (score 6):

Нет, это не возможно стандартными средствами JavaScript.

Все дело в политике безопасности браузера, он требует подтверждения на стороне сервера, что такой запрос разрешен. Если сервер не отошлет специальный заголовок в ответ на Ajax запрос, то сам браузер блокирует ответ от сервера, хотя вы его получаете. Тут остается только использовать обходные пути.

Можете почитать подробнее:
http://learn.javascript.ru/xhr-crossdomain